# what does "Support: Firefox 18+" mean in jQuery1.9.1 source code?

Tags: jquery

I'm reading jquery1.9.1 source code. At the beginning, it says:

```
// Can't do this because several apps including ASP.NET trace
// the stack via arguments.caller.callee and Firefox dies if
// you try to trace through "use strict" call chains. (#13335)
// Support: Firefox 18+
//"use strict";
```

I've read ticket #13335 saying because of apps like ASP.NET trace
call stack via arguments.caller.callee, "use strict" was removed.

but I don't understand what "Support: Firefox 18+" means?

Does it mean, if you use firefox 18+, "use strict" will work fine with
apps like ASP.NET?

Comment: I think it means that if you use `"use strict";` and you happen to get an error, the page will break for users with Firefox 18.

Comment: It's for the "Adults Only" version. :P

Comment: Full ticket, if you're interested:  http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13335

Comment: I think Blender's explanation is kind of reasonable, but "use strict" was introduced since Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1):

The commented `"use strict";` is only enacted if Firefox v18 or newer is being used.

As @blender said, it just breaks the page if that version of FF or newer is being used.

Basically, its for error handling across browsers.

If the later code in the src works with other browsers aside from FF 18+, by including this, it allows for more browsers to use the same src file, making our lives easier.